# How to draw label at specified position inside rectangle?

Tags: labels, circuitikz

How to draw label at specified position inside rectangle at left bottom corner? The goal is to achieve this (label "A1"):

[image]

Comment: Hi, it would be nice if you add a minimal example. The solution is different if you use a `fit` node to draw the dashed box, or if you do it with a `\draw .... rectangle ....` command....

Comment: Trying to find the most simplest way to do it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the option using `fit` and anchors:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    % suppose this is the part of circuit of interest
    \draw (0,3) -- ++(2,0)  (0,0) -- ++(2,0);
    \draw (1,3) coordinate(up) to[generic, name=z1, *-*] (1,0) coordinate(down);
    \node [font=\footnotesize] at (z1.center){$Z_1$};
    % add an auto-fitting node for the dashed part
    \node [draw, dashed, fit=(up) (down) (z1), inner xsep=0.5cm,
        inner ysep=0.8cm](dashed box){};
    % notice that `above right` is the same as `anchor=south west`
    \node [draw, thick, font=\tiny\ttfamily, outer sep=1mm, above right]
        at (dashed box.south west) {A1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See? Your problem is different now, and you invalidate the answers from me and @raffaele-santoro. ***Don't do that.*** The Q&A here are not just for you, they are supposed to help everybody. So: reset the question as it was before; choose one answer and accept it. Then open another question, post a circuit with **just the part with the two impedances you want to surround and label** (***minimal*** example), and explain you want the dissimetry. I promise I'll answer with a (I think) elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[dashed] (-3.25,-5.25) rectangle (3.25,5.25);
        \draw[line width=2pt] (-4,4)--(4,4);
        \draw[line width=2pt] (4,4.2)--(4,3.8);
        \draw[line width=2pt] (-4,-4)--(4,-4);
        \filldraw[line width=2pt] (0,-4) circle(3pt)--(0,4) circle(3pt);
        \filldraw[fill=white,draw,line width=2pt] (-.5,-1) rectangle (.5,1);
        \draw (0,0) node () {\Large \bfseries $Z_1$};
        \draw[line width=2pt] (-3,-5) rectangle (-2,-4.25);
        \draw (-2.5,-4.6) node () {\Large \bfseries $A1$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```